# How to run and connect X Windows in Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, x11, rancher-desktop

I want to connect to Kubernetes pod running under Desktop Rancher (but can be other). On this pod I want to run some test tools using X Windows.

How can I achieve it? What steps is need to done. I think about simple DISPLAY export or X11 Forwarding via SSH.

Currently I am trying connect to localhost using WSL but it not works using host.docker.internal - everything looks good but xeyes is not opening.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to run X applications in your pod and have the output displayed on your local machine?  Assuming X is installed in the pod, ssh with X11 forwarding should be able to do that.

Comment: Kubernetes is usually a little more oriented towards long-running server-type applications.  Where is the display actually running?  How should the application connect to the display?  Why should this run in a distributed clustered environment?